# How to get parent model in child serializer without using depth?

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, i tried to practice django rest api implementation.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Parentmodel(models.Model):
    ptid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ptname = models.CharField(default="",max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ptname

class Studentmodel(models.Model):
    stid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    stname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ptid=models.ForeignKey(Parentmodel,db_column='ptid', related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stname

class Marksmodel(models.Model):
    Marksid=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    maths=models.IntegerField()
    physics=models.IntegerField()
    science=models.IntegerField()
    stid=models.ForeignKey(Studentmodel,db_column='stid', related_name="marks", on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Marksid
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from polls.models import Studentmodel, Marksmodel, Parentmodel

class MarksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model=Marksmodel
    fields="__all__"

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  marks=MarksSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
  class Meta:
    model=Studentmodel
    fields="__all__"

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  student=StudentSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
  class Meta:
    model=Parentmodel
    fields="__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import StudentSerializer, MarksSerializer, ParentSerializer
from .models import Studentmodel, Marksmodel, Parentmodel

class Studentapi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Studentmodel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

class Marksapi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Marksmodel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarksSerializer

class Parentapi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parentmodel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
```

Above code is working fine. I able to get the correct response if i call parent api.

**Parentapi Response :**

```
[
    {
        "ptid": 1,
        "student": [
            {
                "stid": 1,
                "marks": [
                    {
                        "Marksid": 1,
                        "maths": 100,
                        "physics": 100,
                        "science": 123,
                        "stid": 1
                    }
                ],
                "stname": "Nainika",
                "ptid": 1
            }
        ],
        "ptname": "Sabish"
    }
]
```

**Studentapi Response :**

```
[
    {
        "stid": 1,
        "marks": [
            {
                "Marksid": 1,
                "maths": 100,
                "physics": 100,
                "science": 123,
                "stid": 1
            }
        ],
        "stname": "Nainika",
        "ptid": 1
    }
]
```

My question is how to get the parent data in student api?

Comment: You just need to do something similar to what you already do (`marks=MarksSerializer(...)`) by adding a serializer for the parent model as a field in the student model.

Comment: I can't understand. Could you please add the example code.

Comment: I don't understand _why_ you don't understand. Looking at your code you are already using a nested serializer. Giving example code for what you already have appears weird to me. Anyway see the documentation here [Dealing with nested objects (DRF docs)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)